# Using Python to test HTTP APIs

Tags: python, json, httprequest

I'm fairly new to Python programming and I don't know all the libraries needed for the following.

I would like to use Python to test some HTTP APIs. Mainly I want to use OAuth and make a few JSON calls. The APIs in question can be found on: https://developers.trustpilot.com/authentication and the generate product review link (I can only use one link)

I want to authenticate myself and then generate a product review link in one step. So far I've been using the Advanced REST client (ARC) to make these calls individually. I could also use .arc files if you think it's easier.

The idea would be make these calls successively in one go. So it would be something along the lines:

1) Make the authentication call.

The HTTP Method looks like this:
https://api.trustpilot.com/v1/oauth/oauth-business-users-for-applications/accesstoken
Method Post:

Header
Authorization: Basic Base64encode(APIkey:Secret)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Payload:
grant_type=password&username=user@mail.com&password=SomePass

Translate this bit into Python basically.

1.a) Add a header to the call

Header Authorization: base64encode hash Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

1.b) Add a payload to the call

Payload: grant_type=password&username

4) Receive the token from call made in step 1) (Result is format)

"access token": Auth_token

5) Take the token and use it in creating a product review.

5.a) Add the token in the header

Header: Authorization: Bearer Auth_token

6.a) Add a JSON payload to the call made in step 5.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
Import requests

header = {'Authorization: Basic NnNrQUprTWRHTU5VSXJGYXBVRGxack1oT01oTUFRZHI6QTFvOGJjRUNDdUxBTmVqUQ==}','Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
payload = {'grant_type=password&username=email@address.com&password=SomePassword'}
r = requests.post('https://api.trustpilot.com/v1/oauth/oauth-business-users-for-applications/accesstoken', headers=header, params=payload )
```

Ideally I want to create the requests.post(url, header, payload) and then return what the server answers in JSON format. I think that print r.text would do the last part.

So this is the code I have writtent (that works now):

```
import requests
import getpass
import json
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

header = {'grant_type':'password' , 'username':'mail@maildomain.com', 'password':'YourPassword'}
username= "YOURAPIKEY" #APIKey
password= "YOURSECRET" #Secret
res = requests.post(
    'URL/v1/oauth/oauth-business-users-for-applications/accesstoken',
    auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password),  # basic authentication
    data=header)

#print(res.content) #See content of the call result.

data = res.json()  # get response as parsed json (will return a dict)
auth_token = data.get('access_token')
```

Comment: `json.loads()`, `json.dumps()` are quite good start. Also requests accept named argument `headers` as dict.

Comment: Instead of implementing the OAuth2 flow yourself, have you looked at e.g. [Requests-OAuthLib](https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)? Their documentation has a few tutorials for different OAuth providers.

Comment: I was hoping to just Authenticate with the HTTP Post request. Normally there is an Authorization part comprised of a base64 encoded APIKey and Secret, along with the user and password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`requests` can do all  what you ask without any work from your part.

See the doc for [authentication](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/), [parameters](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls), [json output](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content), [json input](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)

> Make the authentication call.

```
import requests
import getpass

from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

username = raw_input('Username: ')
password = getpass.getpass('Password: ')

res = requests.post(
    'https://api.trustpilot.com/v1/oauth/oauth-business-users-for-applications/accesstoken',
    auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password),  # basic authentication
    params={  # url parameters
        'grant_type': 'password',
        'username': 'email@address.com',
        'password': 'SomePassword'
    })
```

> Receive the token from call made in step 1) (Result is format)

```
# res = requests.post.....
data = res.json()  # get response as parsed json (will return a dict)
auth_token = data.get('access token')
```

> Take the token and use it in creating a product review.

```
request.post(
    '.../product_review',
    headers={
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth_token
    },
    json={'my': 'payload'})  # send data as json
```

Comment: In the Authentication process for the HTTP Post call I also have an authorization part in the header. It's comprised of an APIKey and Secret base64 encoded. So the header would have something like Authorization: Basic base64hash. Is there any way to provide those as the header?

Comment: `HTTPBasicAuth(username, password)` will be your `API KEY` and `API SECRET`. `requests` will put it in the header `Authorization` correctly.

Comment: Will it also do the base64encode automatically? I suspect I need to do this separately. The HTTP Call I make looks like this:

The HTTP Method looks like this: https://api.trustpilot.com/v1/oauth/oauth-business-users-for-applications/accesstoken 
Method Post

Header Authorization: Basic Base64encode(APIkey:Secret) Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Payload: grant_type=password&username=user@mail.com&password=SomePass

Comment: Is will be base64 encoded as `base64(API KEY:API SECRET)` just like the api wants :).

Comment: I see. So where do I input the user@mail.com and password for said username?
If I read the code correctly, the params= part will just use the APIKey and Secret. Or do I just hardcode them in the param section?

I also get an error when I try to run the code:
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth_token
TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly

Comment: replace in my code `username` and `password` by your `API KEY` and `API SECRET`.  `requests` will send it base64 encoded for you (Exactly as the api wants). Replace `email@address.com` and `SomePassword` in param by valid credentials. To check the return, `print(res.content)`.  You will see if the api return an error or not. Then for the next steps, you need a successful authentication (`NoneType` will be the value of `auth_token` if an error occurs, and that is why the next step fail. My code shows everything, could you accept the answer ?

Comment: I think the grant type isn't recognized properly. I get the following error.

b'{"reason":"Unknown grant_type"} '
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alma\Google Drive\Trainings\APIs with Neven\Python API Calling.
py", line 25, in <module>
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth_token
TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly